# How to add a placeholder to the protected post password input

Tags: forms, password, input

When a post is protected, its content looks like:

```
// This content is password protected. To view it please enter your password below:
// Password: [_______________] [Enter]
```

How do I add a placeholder to that `<input>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved via a hook, called `the_password_form`:

```
function my_theme_password_placeholder($output) {
    $placeholder = 'Hello!';
    $search = 'type="password"';
    return str_replace($search, $search . " placeholder=\"$placeholder\"", $output);
}
add_filter('the_password_form', 'my_theme_password_placeholder');
```

A `str_replace` searches for the string `type="password"` inside the output. This gives an attribute to the `<input>` indicating it's of type `password`. The replacement string contains the searched one *plus* the `placeholder` attribute too.

Comment: This should be selected as answer! Just copy and paste it into a PHP inserter plugin. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the password field has an 'id' value, a bit of Javascript might be better.

The wp-admin login page uses a password id of 'user-pass', so place this in your function used with the add_filter('the_password_form', 'my_theme_password_placeholder);

```
function my_theme_password_placeholder() {
?>
<script>
document.getElementById("password-field-id").placeholder = "Type password here.."; 
</script>
<?php 
return;}

add_filter('the_password_form') 'my_theme_password_placeholder');
```

This will place the `Type password here..` text inside the password field.

This will ensure that any placeholder value is the one you set, overwriting any existing placeholder value. You could adjust the function to pass a parameter containing the string to display as a placeholder.

Of course, if the visitor has disabled JavaScript, this won't work. But that is (IMHO) a small minority of site visitors.